# Using the last image in an array

Tags: html, knockout.js

Sorry if wrong format or dumb question, I'm new to this.  I use knockout js and normally use it to find a image with an index and display it, however, I'm wondering if it is possible to ensure it is the last image that gets used regardless of index number, below is an example of the code I currently use.

```
  <div style="position: absolute; right: 0px; bottom: 0px">
    <!-- ko foreach: PropertyDetails().Images() -->
    <!-- ko if: DocumentSubType().SystemName() === "Photo" -->
    <!-- ko if: $index() === 7 -->
    <div
      data-bind="attr:{id: 'picture-' + Id() }, widget: {
                kind: 'ImageManipulator',
                config: {
                    width: '546px',
                    height: '380px',
                    imageUrl: Url().indexOf('http://www.example.com/estate-agent-software/ImageResizeHandler.do') == -1 ? Url() + '?width=NaN' : Url() + '&width=NaN'
                },
                identification: {
                    Id: 'property-image-' + Id()
                }}"
    ></div>
    <!--/ko-->
    <!--/ko-->
    <!--/ko-->
  </div>
```

Comment: I would extend your image object and add there a field called isLast. UI shouldn't know and care about indexes and images count :)

Answer (score 1):

changing out the last ko if: to

```
 <!-- ko if: $index() === $parent.PropertyDetails().Images().length - 1 -->
```

did the trick, just in-case anyone else comes across this question :)